# Forbidden access to socket message when running Python 2.7 web service locally on Windows 10

Tags: windows, python-2.7, web-services

I have a Python 2.7 web service which uses Pyramid libraries. The service works fine on Linux machines, but when run locally on Windows 10 I get the following error when making post requests: "error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions"

I can make get requests via a browser with no problems. Only post requests via an application seem to result in this error message.

I have tried turning off both Kaspersky anti-virus and the Windows firewall, but I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason could be that the current user account lacks sufficient permissions to bind to the port you have provided (port 80?). Try with a higher port(>6000 or something)

You can specify this configuration in your .ini file under the *[server:main]* section

For instance,

```
[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 127.0.0.1
port = 6543
```

Comment: Thanks, Sanaha, for the reply. It's a good idea, but I'm already using port 8000.